# Do the drones crashing hurt my chickens?

Tags: egg-inc

If I have a good number of chickens hatched and running to the barn, and I crash a drone out of the sky, does it affect my chickens? Or will they count towards my chicken count regardless if a drone crashes in the middle of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drones don't affect chickens at all, they just provide extra money, I have the game myself and I've got tachyon eggs, drones literally go through everything, including buildings so I doubt they kill your chickens..

Comment: Awesome, I figured that was probably the case when I saw them fly through the buildings but I wanted to check before I lost any chickens.